# Has anyone tried using functional near-infrared spectropathy to quantitively measure sodium concentrations in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, biophysics

Functional near-infrared spectropathy "fNIRS", is a biophysics/medical technique that uses the near-infrared part of the electromagnetic spectrum (around 680nm to 810nm in wavelength) to image the blood oxygenation level dependent "BOLD" effect in the brain to image brain function [for more on BOLD look here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1631079/). Recently, in 2018 a study was done [link to study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6237845/) showing that High-field MRI could be used to functionally image sodium quantitively in the brain.
I'm wondering if the same thing (functional sodium imaging) can be done with fNIRS or an Infrared spectropathy type deal.

Does anyone know if this has been attempted?

Comment: How would you get near infrared through the skull?

Comment: @Chris take a look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_near-infrared_spectroscopy)